# How do I implement the `fromObject` method for customize class in FabricJS (with typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, fabricjs

I am trying to make a customize class for a custom object. The object needs to be load with JSON, so I would have to implement fromObject method.

I use Typescript and FabricJS v5.3.0.

When i load my json with `canvas.loadFromJSON(...)` i have this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromObject')

My custom class :

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import { IRectOptions } from 'fabric/fabric-impl';

...

export class CustomRect extends fabric.Rect {

    public readonly type = 'customrect';
    public echo = {
        ...
    };

    constructor(options: ICustomRectOptions) {
        super(options);
        this.echo = options.echo || this.echo;
    }

    toObject(propertiesToInclude?: string[]) {
        propertiesToInclude = (propertiesToInclude || []).concat(
            ['echo']
        );
        return super.toObject(propertiesToInclude);
    }

    static fromObject(object: any): CustomRect {
        return new CustomRect(object);
    }

    _render(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        super._render(ctx);
    }
}
```

I tried with a normal and static method, but always the same error message.